# ctools modal form shows ugly access denied

Tags: chaos-tool-suite, javascript

I have made a modal form using ctools. The form works okay when the user has access rights, but with no access rights an empty modal form is showing and I get a browser error saying

"An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code 403" (and a lot of debugging information)

Is this a flaw in ctools modal or am I missing something?

In case of access denied I would like to fall back to a standard access denied message.

Comment: I now know that the error is displayed by Drupal.ajaxError in drupal.js. So I am guessing that ctools modal.js should try to do some error handling itself if at all possible.

Comment: You can also check user permission in your code.

Comment: I think that in reality this situation would never occur because the link would not exists. Still the user could type in a invalid url using the ajax suffix and get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer this myself. There is no mentioning of this issue in the CTools project itself but the issue is mentioned at the CTools Auto-modal project https://drupal.org/node/1450232

There is also a solution:

- implement hook_page_delivery_callback_alter
- check if callback is made by one of your ajax links
- if so, check is user has access by using menu_get_item and inspecting the resulting router item
- if access is ok, do nothing
- if access denied or page not found, render a message

The solution at CTools Auto-modal renders the message in the CTools modal box. But I preferred to kill the CTools modal and just do nothing:

```
$commands[] = ctools_modal_command_dismiss();
print ajax_render($commands);
exit();
```

This way the dreaded drupal ajax error will never appear.